# How to create a hidden factory?

Tags: python

I know it's been covered before but I'm just not getting it...

I want to create a class that is called with a filename but, depending on the filename's extension, it morphs to one of several subclasses. It think its a factory pattern, and I've done that before using a staticmethod, but I'm trying now, not entirely for kicks, to do it with a common instantiation of the base class.  Is this possible?

```
 >>> foo = FileClass('foo.txt')
 >>> type(foo)
 <type 'TextFileClass'>

 >>> foo = FileClass('foo.rtf')
 >>> type(foo)
 <type 'RTFFileClass'>
```

Thats not actual output but what I'm hoping to achieve.  I've being trying crazy stuff and must be way off the track.  At the moment I've implemented a `__new__` routine in `FileClass` but can't seem to it right.  There seem to be a number of ways to do it?  What's the right one?

Comment: You can create a separate function if it makes you feel better. Like `def create_the_right_object(filename):`

Comment: @JBernardo yeah, but i could, but that's just so old hat ;-)

Comment: Then just use `__new__`. It will work just like the function I described above... Just return whatever you like

Comment: classes aren't really meant to know about their subclasses. Why can't `FileClass` just be a factory function?

Comment: Is it something like mime type? http://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html

Comment: @gnibbler I kinda agree, but then what about `.__subclasses__()`. Also I told him to use a factory function, "but that's just so old hat"

Comment: @JBernardo, Been there. Abused `__subclasses__`. Worked ok, but I wouldn't recommend it

Comment: @gnibbler I felt tempted of using it when I was creating some code with factories for metaclasses and I needed to forge `__instancecheck__` to pretend some objects were instances of its children classes. But I managed doing the check in the opposite direction.

Comment: @gnibbler Is 'factory function' a thing? Or is it a 'function factory'?

Comment: @JBernardo I'm regretting the 'old hat' comment now :-)  That is the KISS solution I was overlooking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not just use a factory function?

```
class BaseFile(object):
    """Inherit these common methods and properties"""
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname

    def is_pretty(self):
        NotImplemented

class TextFileClass(BaseFile): 
    def is_pretty(self):
        return False

class RTFFileClass(BaseFile):
    def is_pretty(self):
        return True

def createFileClass(fname):
    if fname.endswith('.txt'):
        return TextFileClass(fname)
    elif fname.endswith('.rtf'):
        return RTFFileClass(fname)
    else:
        raise Exception, 'unknown file format'

FileClass = createFileClass
```

Produces:

```
>>> foo = FileClass('foo.txt')
>>> type(foo)
<class '__main__.TextFileClass'>

>>> foo = FileClass('foo.rtf')
>>> type(foo)
<class '__main__.RTFFileClass'>
```

Comment: Actually that's a low tech approach. I like that. Does it work?

Comment: @JohnMee sorry for not seeing the 'old hat' comment, but why it's "low tech"? Is it merely because of the use of function but not class?

Comment: 'low tech' meaning that even python noobs could understand it; no mucking about python constructors.

Comment: @JohnMee, Java noobs etc. will be able to understand it more easily too

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with doing this with `__new__` is, if `FileClass.__new__` calls the `TextFileClass` constructor, how is `TextFileClass` going to `__new__` up an instance to return?

To solve this, we can test what `cls` is in `__new__`, so we don't interfere with child classes' `__new__`:

```
def __new__(cls, filename):
    if cls is FileClass:
        return cls._factory(filename)
    return super(FileClass, cls).__new__(cls, filename)
```

When `FileClass('foo.txt')` is called, Python calls `__init__` on the object returned from `__new__` if it's an instance of `FileClass`, so we have to use `TextFileClass.__new__('foo.txt')` instead of `TextFileClass('foo.txt')`:

```
@classmethod
def _factory(cls, filename):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        return TextFileClass.__new__(filename)
    elif filename.endswith('.rtf'):
        return RTFFileClass.__new__(filename)
    ...
```

All in all, it's probably not worth doing things this way. A factory function or factory method is much easier to get right.

Comment: Ah, this edit is better as I was just about to mention the recursion loop. Let me try it...

Comment: Hmmm. It calls both new and init repeatedly. This is probably just sweet for a vanilla case but my actual problem has unmentioned complexities which mess around with the calling arguments; so I'm finding this approach really hard to get right, which makes me worry it might be a bit too tricky for my successors here. :-(

Answer (score 0):

If `FileClass` can't be a factory function, you can apply the [Handle/Body](http://tinf2.vub.ac.be/~dvermeir/c++/EuroPLoP98.html#HandleBody) pattern (or the derived [Envelope/Letter](http://tinf2.vub.ac.be/~dvermeir/c++/EuroPLoP98.html#EnvelopeLetter) pattern) to have `FileClass` instantiate the implementation class, hold it in a field and proxy method calls to it. The consumer won't see the child classes in the type of the variables, but the interface will be present, which is the important thing.